# Designing a frequency detection circuit

Tags: frequency, detection, pic16f877a

Hi i was wondering if its possible  to make a digital frequency detection signal which detects which generation is being used by nearby mobile phone ie:gsm 3g 4g the frequency band varies according each phone using pic16f877a

Comment: It's possible, as most things are.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Some things are possible and some aren't. Unfortunately, your question is lacks a great deal of detail on what you have, what exactly you are trying to do and why. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Your question is similar to asking: "Can I cook a 3-course meal using this knife <a link to some knife is included>". The answer would be: sure, but you don't have to use that particular knife (you write: pic16f877a but that is irrelevant, any microcontroller could be used), depending on the ingredients, maybe I do not need a knife (make a circuit **without** a microcontroller), you also need **much more than a knife** to cook a meal (you need much more than just a microcontroller). If you have **no cooking skills at all** this will be a hard (what circuit design skills do you have?).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. As a start, you need to explore something called Software Defined Radio (SDR). Get a Realtek RTL2832 dongle (Ebay, $10) and set up a Linux system to plug it into. Then install GNURadio and run a spectrum analyzer type of script (think: fast fourier transform). Now tune to cellular bands appropriate for your region of the world. Then look for tell-tale shapes in the amplitude versus frequency data.

GSM 2G uses time-division-multiplexing within channels that are 200khz wide.
3G uses wide-CDMA which occupies 5MHz although there are 0.58MHz guard bands surrounding a 3.84MHz channel (256x 15kbps)
4G/LTE uses orthogonal frequency division multiplexing and has a much wider footprint. 1.5, 6, 10, 15, 20MHz.

The Realtek dongle's usable range is 76 to 1700 MHz, so you're going to be limited unless you spend substantially more money. I have two Ettus B200 boards which can tune up to 6GHz. Note that you need to have an appropriate antenna attached for the band you're working in.

Here in the 'States it is generally legal to run a spectrum analysis. No one will raise an eyebrow if I have on my screen a real-time FFT of T-Mobile's nearest cell tower in the 700MHz band. There are even applications that will scan for a cell tower then uses its output as an extremely high accuracy clock source.

Without knowing what you have in mind I can only suggest you get into SDR, download and compile others' applications, then get familiar with what 2G,3G,4G spectrum usage looks like and go from there..

https://www.rtl-sdr.com/